# I need help in the custom Font and TextView

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I'm new in android working on an app that gives the user info about all font's of Google.
For that, I need to make an app with a TextView [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ahps.png)

On click of the TextView, the font will change With text.

I'm thinking about using onclicklistener

Comment: did you search in google before asking question ?

Comment: @FaizMir yes I do only custom font Topic I got from google, Only custom font is not my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put `"your_font.ttf"` file in asset folder then import it with

```
Typeface custom_font_1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "your_font.ttf");
```

then assign it to your `showCaseTextView` with this

```
   showCaseTextView.setTypeFace(custom_font_1);
```

then in your `onClickListener` of `showCaseTextView`  to change your `specifiedTextView` font do like this

```
   specifiedTextView.setTypeFace(custom_font_1);
```

and repeat it for other fonts.

Comment: Thanq this help me a lot,

Comment: happy to hear that krishna

Comment: I need a Little help how can I contact you Please Let me know

Comment: you can contact my telegram or whats app account
+98-935-589-0011

Comment: sorry I don't use any of them your Email Or any Social account

Answer (score 0):

**Have 2 way to archive this**

**1st way**

```
public class FontCache {

    private static HashMap<String, Typeface> fontCache = new HashMap<>();

    public static Typeface getTypeface(String fontname, Context context) {
        Typeface typeface = fontCache.get(fontname);

        if (typeface == null) {
            try {
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

            fontCache.put(fontname, typeface);
        }

        return typeface;
    }
}
```

This caches the fonts while minimizing the number of accesses to the assets. Now, since we've a method to access our custom font, let's implement a class, which extends TextView.

Extending TextView
Next, we'll create a new Java class, which extends TextView. This allows us to use that class in all XML views. It inherits all functionality and properties of a regular TextView; but adds our custom font.

Once again, we're taking a peek at the source code of our eat foody project. The code might look complex for a second, but is straight-forward:

```
public class EatFoodyTextView extends TextView {

    public EatFoodyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public EatFoodyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public EatFoodyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
        Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf", context);
        setTypeface(customFont);
    }
}
```

The first three methods are just constructors, which we override to call a single method applyCustomFont(). That method is the important piece of the puzzle. It simply gets the (hopefully cached) font from our FontCache class. Lastly, we've to call setTypeface() with the font and we're almost done. In case you're wondering, we can call the setTypeface() directly (and not on a TextView object), since we're extending the TextView class.

Using the Class
You might wonder, if so much preparation is worth the effort. In this section you'll see that it is indeed. Because all you've left to do is use the class in an XML view and it automatically has your custom font. There is no Java code necessary!

```
<RelativeLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.futurestudio.foody.views.EatFoodyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/eat_foody_green_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Future Studio Blog"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, you can continue to use all niceties (e.g. textSize, textColor) of TextView. Now, just replace all  elements with the class we just created, for example  and you applied your custom font everywhere!
(Ref: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/custom-fonts-on-android-extending-textview)

**2nd way**
Follow Google guide support from API 26 (Android 8) https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

**Make change between textview to change font**

```
<RelativeLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/eat_foody_green_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Future Studio Blog"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"/>
    <com.futurestudio.foody.views.EatFoodyTextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_custom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/eat_foody_green_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Future Studio Blog"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

attention at `android:visibility="gone"`
in Activity you use this code to toggle between 2 TextViews

```
    final TextView normalTextView = findViewById(R.id.textview_normal);
    final TextView customTextView = findViewById(R.id.textview_custom);

    normalTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            normalTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    customTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            normalTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: On click of the TixtView the font did not change

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do this using OnClickListener

Comment: I suggest you to use 2 textview (1 normal, 1 custom font). onClickListener just for toggle visibility to show between 2 textview

Comment: how can I do that any help

Comment: I add more code for solution toggle 2 TextView between normal font and custom font

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own custom font with TextView, EditText, Button etc.. by using android attributes.

## How to

**-Here are some steps to use:**

1.Create attribute file (res->values->attrs.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TextElement">
        <attr name="font" format="string"/>
        <attr name="underline" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

2.Create Custom TextView class (anywhere in java folder)
3. Use attributes inside your layout file
4. and just run your code.

Here is the full example of your question, you can go through this exmaple:

[Full Demonstration](http://androiderstack.com/index.php/2017/08/14/use-custom-font-in-textview-edittext-and-button-in-android/)

Comment: Can I use this with OnClick it will help

Comment: this code if for custom view i want the font change on click